# \end{center} but still centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center

I am centering a text:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\partpageend}{} %% can write after part title
\usepackage{graphicx}



\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} 
        \par\vfill
}

\begin{document}
    
    \part{This is a title}
    
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{This text is being centered and that's what I want.}
        \vfill
    \end{center}
    
    \newpage
    
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.
This text should not be centered anymore.

\end{document}
```

But after `\end{center}` everything else is still being centered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that shows this problem such that others can copy and test the code as is on their system to confirm or deny the issue.

Comment: I have edited the opening posting.

Comment: This is probably caused by the `\centering` in your `\beforepartskip`. Surround that with another pair of braces: `{\centering ... \par\vfill}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has already been noted by @HeikoTheißen in a comment, the centering issue you're experiencing arises because the `\centering` command in the definition of `\beforepartskip` is not in a (TeX) group and hence persists. The fact that the document also features, separately, a `center` *environment*, is immaterial.

One way to fix this is to replace

```
\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image} 
        \par}\vfill
}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
        \par}\vfill
}
```

Can you spot the extra instances of `{` and `}`?

Comment: Should the `\par` be inside the group or not?

Comment: @daleif - I've updated my answer to reflect your and egreg's points.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Will \centering be obsolete soon?

Comment: @Brayanokles - You asked, "Will `\centering` be obsolete soon?" Absolutely not. The LaTeX *environment* called `center` is actually defined around the *command* called `\centering`.